# hibernate doesn't close connections when there is concurrency

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, apache-axis

Good morning,

I'm testing a data base with concurrency.

The test is launch 50 request with JMeter, the code save a register in data base and measure the time

The problem is that hibernate is not close any the sessión. My database has 200 connections.

The server be blocked and there are request never end.

My Hibernate cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="prueba">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PROD</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orclpdb1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">PROD</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">PROD</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  <property name="connection.pool_size">200</property>  

  <mapping class="es.pers.com.accesobd.model.TestTable"/>
  <mapping class="es.pers.com.accesobd.model.TestTableId"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Class HibernateUtil

```
package es.pers.com.control;
    import java.io.File;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

        public class HibernateUtil {

            private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

            public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
                try {
                    // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
                    configuration.configure(new File("C:\\workspace\\bdd\\hibernate.cfg.xml"));
                    System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded");

                    ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry.buildServiceRegistry());

                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    System.out.println("RuntimeException");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception");
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                }
                return sessionFactory;
            }


            public static void closeSessionFactory(){
                try {
                    sessionFactory.close();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                }
            }
        }
```

The code saves in database:

```
public void saveDB(){
Session session =null;
        try {

            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();


            TestTable pru = new TestTable();
            TestTableId id = new TestTableId();
            long info = System.currentTimeMillis();
            id.setCampo1(info+"1");
            id.setCampo2(info+"2");
            id.setCampo3(info+"3");
            id.setCampo4(info+"4");
            id.setCampo5(info+"5");

            pru.setId(id);
            long ini = System.currentTimeMillis();
            session.save(pru);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("# Tiempo: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-ini));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(null!=session) {
                try {
                    session.close();
                    HibernateUtil.closeSessionFactory();

                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    System.out.println("Error close connection");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And the JBoss error:

```
11:07:39,948 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19) org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
11:07:39,952 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
11:07:39,954 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
11:07:39,955 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
11:07:39,956 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
11:07:39,958 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
11:07:39,959 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
11:07:39,961 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
11:07:39,962 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1309)
11:07:39,963 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at es.pers.com.servicios.wsimpl.tra.ws.WS_retSkeleton.ejecutarLogica(WS_retSkeleton.java:143)
11:07:39,965 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at es.pers.com.servicios.wsimpl.AbstractSkeleton.ejecutar(AbstractSkeleton.java:82)
11:07:39,974 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at es.pers.com.servicios.wsimpl.AbstractSkeleton.ejecutarOperacionWS(AbstractSkeleton.java:383)
11:07:39,976 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at es.pers.com.servicios.wsimpl.tra.ws.WS_retSkeleton.Op(WS_retSkeleton.java:53)
11:07:39,978 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at es.pers.com.logica.logicaimpl.MessageReceiverInOut.generateEnvelope(MessageReceiverInOut.java:203)
11:07:39,979 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at es.pers.com.logica.logicaimpl.MessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(MessageReceiverInOut.java:56)
11:07:39,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
11:07:39,982 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
11:07:39,984 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
11:07:39,985 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
11:07:39,986 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
11:07:39,988 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
11:07:39,989 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
11:07:39,991 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
11:07:39,992 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
11:07:39,994 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
11:07:39,995 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
11:07:39,996 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
11:07:40,005 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
11:07:40,007 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
11:07:40,009 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
11:07:40,010 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
11:07:40,011 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
11:07:40,012 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
11:07:40,014 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
11:07:40,015 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
11:07:40,017 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
11:07:40,018 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
11:07:40,019 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19) ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
11:07:40,020 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)
11:07:40,021 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
11:07:40,023 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
11:07:40,026 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
11:07:40,027 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
11:07:40,028 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
11:07:40,029 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
11:07:40,031 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
11:07:40,038 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
11:07:40,040 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
11:07:40,041 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
11:07:40,042 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
11:07:40,043 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173)
11:07:40,045 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:277)
11:07:40,046 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
11:07:40,048 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   ... 31 more
11:07:40,049 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19) Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
11:07:40,051 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19) ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
11:07:40,052 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)
11:07:40,053 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:361)
11:07:40,054 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
11:07:40,056 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
11:07:40,057 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-19)   ... 40 more
```

Comment: it's just for this example. I normally opening the session to start web services. This is a dumb example, with the real app occurs the same